# Remove upload text after uploading picture

Tags: php, html

So what I'm trying to do is simple: After the picture is uploaded I want the "upload picture here" button and text gone so the picture, and its info has room on the page. I think I need an if statement that if the picture is uploaded successfully, then remove or exit the upload html. I dont know though.
 I've cut everything I believe is unecessary from the code, so I dont suppose it will make sense as is.

```
    <div id="upload">
      <h2>Last opp et bilde her!</h2>
      <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <td><input type="file" name="filbane" size="60"/></td>
        <input type="image" name="submit" src="./upload.png" width="25px" height="25px" border="0" alt="Submit" />
    </center>
</form>
</div>
<?php


  if (empty($_FILES['filbane']['name'])) {
    die;
  }


else {

  $temp_fil = $_FILES['filbane']['tmp_name'];
  //Blir for eksempel bilder/navn.jpg
  $filnavn="Opplastetbilder/" . $_FILES['filbane']['name'];
  //Må derfor kopiere fra denne over til et kjent sted/navn
  $allowed = array('image/gif','image/png','image/jpeg','image/jpg');
  $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $filename = $_FILES['filbane']['type'];

  if(!in_array($filename,$allowed) ) {
    die ("<br><br><br><br><br>Du har lastet opp en fil med feil filtype, vennligst prøv igjen. <br> Vi tar bare imot png, jpg eller gif"
    );
  }

  move_uploaded_file($temp_fil, $filnavn)
    or die ("En feil oppstod, kunne ikke kopiere fil!
    <br>
    "
    );


    $filtype = $_FILES['filbane']['type'];

    $storrelse = $_FILES['filbane']['size'];


    print "<br><br><br><br><br><h3> Dette bildet ble lastet opp</h3>";



    if (strstr($filtype, "jpeg") || strstr($filtype, "jpg") || strstr($filtype, "gif") || strstr($filtype, "png") ) {
      print "<br><br><br><br><img src= '$filnavn' height='200' align='center' />";
    }

    //Vis filnavn, type og størrelse
    print "<br><br>Filnavn: $filnavn <p>";
    print "Type: $filtype<p>";
    print "Størrelse: $storrelse byte <p>";
    print "<a href = './bilde.php'><button>Last opp nytt bilde</button></div>";
    print "<a href = './index.php'><button>Hjem</button><br>";

  }

?>
```

Comment: Hard to give sample with fragmented script. May be this: if (isset($_FILE['filbane'])) { // your php script } else { echo '<div id="upload">your form</div>'; }

Comment: Added the whole code

Comment: Basically if you upload, it should remove the "upload" feature and just show the result.

Comment: Use Jquery with ajax calls to do so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use isset() to determine $_FILES['filbane'] is submitted. Otherwise, show form

```
<?php
$error = '';
if (isset($_FILES['filbane']['name'])) {

  $temp_fil = $_FILES['filbane']['tmp_name'];
  //Blir for eksempel bilder/navn.jpg
  $filnavn = "Opplastetbilder/" . $_FILES['filbane']['name'];
  //Må derfor kopiere fra denne over til et kjent sted/navn
  $allowed = array('image/gif','image/png','image/jpeg','image/jpg');
  // $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); <==
  $ext = pathinfo($filnavn, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $filename = $_FILES['filbane']['type'];

  if (!in_array($filename,$allowed) ) {
    $error = "<br><br><br><br><br>Du har lastet opp en fil med feil filtype, vennligst prøv igjen. <br> Vi tar bare imot png, jpg eller gif<br>";
  } else {
        if (!move_uploaded_file($temp_fil, $filnavn)) {
            $error = "En feil oppstod, kunne ikke kopiere fil!<br>";
        } else {
            print "Upload Successfully";
            $filtype = $_FILES['filbane']['type'];
            $storrelse = $_FILES['filbane']['size'];

            if (strstr($filtype, "jpeg") || strstr($filtype, "jpg") || strstr($filtype, "gif") || strstr($filtype, "png") ) {
                print "<br><br><br><br><img src= '$filnavn' height='200' align='center' />";
            }

            //Vis filnavn, type og størrelse
            print "<br><br><p>Filnavn: $filnavn </p>";
            print "<p>Type: $filtype</p>";
            print "<p>Størrelse: $storrelse byte </p>";
            print "<a href = './bilde.php'><button>Last opp nytt bilde</button></div>";
            print "<a href = './index.php'><button>Hjem</button><br>";
        }
  }
} else {
?>
    <?php echo $error; ?>
    <div id="upload">
      <h2>Last opp et bilde her!</h2>
      <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <td><input type="file" name="filbane" size="60"/></td>
        <input type="image" name="submit" src="./upload.png" width="25px" height="25px" border="0" alt="Submit" />
                <!-- </center> -->
            </form>
        </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Had issues using the code u sent, where am I supposed to have the last part where I print the filetype, size and such of the image?

Comment: I have updated the code again and fixed your <p> tags. Make sure html tags are open and closed properly to avoid unexpected result. And you still have missing open <div>